# Fill a <td> with a jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, innerhtml

I'm trying to make an ajax call for each of a series of 's and replace the inner html of the td with processed data from the ajax call.

As I'm locked to an ecommerce cms system my ajax call is a complete page with the following string:
**!#249,00!#349,00**!#5 ltr!#**

the code below splits this to:
var pprices = ['','249,00','349,00'];
var plabels = ['','5 ltr',''];

Note: the numbers in pprices uses comma instead of full stop.

The problem is that the last line: $(this).html(endprice); 
fills the cell with the default value '999999' and not the new value. It seems that the line is executed before the ajax call is completed.

**How do ensure that data found in the for loop is sent to the td?**

My current code is this:

```
  $(".pricetag").each( function() {
  var pgroup = $(this).attr('group');
  var plink = "Default.aspx?ID=14&groupid=" + pgroup + "&mode=-1";
  var endprice = "999999";
  var endlabel = "";
  $.ajax({url:plink,done:function(result){
    pprices = result.split("**")[1];
    plabels = result.split("**")[2];
    prices = pprices.split("!#");
    labels = plabels.split("!#");
    for(i=0;i<prices.length;i++) { 
        j=parseInt(prices[i]); k=parseInt(endprice); 
        if(j!=0 && j<k) { endprice = prices[i]; endlabel = labels[i]; }}
  }});
  $(this).html(endprice);
  });
```

HTML:

```
<table><tr>
  <td> label </td>
  <td class="pricetag" group="<!--@Ecom:Group.ID-->"> price </td>
</tr></table>
```

The: <!--@Ecom:Group.ID--> fetches an id from the ecommerce system.

Comment: I wouldn't make multiple ajax requests for each td, this seems expensive.  I would make one call and return the data then make a new table based upon this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the jQuery.ajax documentation, it doesn't look to me like `done:` is a valid setting. I think you want to use either `success:` or call done() on the jqXHR object returned from $.ajax().

That said, you are correct in your assumption that 'the line is executed before the ajax call is completed'... you need to move that line into your success handler function, something like:

```
$.ajax({url:plink,
        context: $(this),
        success:function(result){
            pprices = result.split("**")[1];
            plabels = result.split("**")[2];
            prices = pprices.split("!#");
            labels = plabels.split("!#");
            for(i=0;i<prices.length;i++) { 
                j=parseInt(prices[i]); k=parseInt(endprice); 
                if(j!=0 && j<k) { endprice = prices[i]; endlabel = labels[i]; }}
            $(this).html(endprice);
       }});
```

Note that I added the context setting, to pass in `this` from the `each()`, so that the success function is working with the right `this`.

I didn't test this. but I believe it should work. You may want to check the [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) docs if you have trouble.

Comment: Can this somehow be run at the server rather than at client? Right now it executes as the page loads. And as mentioned in the comment above it is a slow process...

Comment: Typically, one would use code like this to update a page with new information after the page loads, to avoid reloading a lot of content that is not changing. If you are only running this when the page loads, and you are doing this for a bunch of values, then moving the processing to the server is a probably a good idea. How you would go about doing it depends on what programming language you are using on the server.

Comment: This only runs once as the page loads. The server is an aspx server and as I only have experience with php I'm kinda lost. I have created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891178/fill-tds-as-page-is-generated-with-ajax-call-on-aspx-page